# How to convert _JsonMap to Map in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have response body with type _JsonMap

[image]

How I can convert it into standard Json? I cannot find way to extract map with my data from this object

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dart has a built-in library called `dart:convert` which lets you convert data types.

You can use [`jsonDecode(String source)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) function to convert JSON strings to dart map

> #### jsonDecode function
>
> ```dart
> dynamic jsonDecode(
> String source,
> {Object? reviver(
> Object? key,
> Object? value
> )?}
> )
> ```
>
> Parses the string and returns the resulting Json object.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
...

final Map map = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

If you are trying to parse a JSON that is not in string format
you can just use

```dart
final Map map = Map.from(response.body);
```

Comment: Still same problem. body is in _JsonMap type and I don't know why.

`dataResponseToItemFromList(Map.from(snapshot.data!.body));`

At debug console I receive:

`════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'`

Comment: final Map map = Map.from(response.body); Worked for me thanks

Comment: @TerblancheDaniel you should add your comment as an answer weirdly I tried many ways to convert it but none of them works, thank you

Answer (score 3):

`final Map map = Map.from(response.body);`

answer from @Terblanche Daniel
worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Function to parse

```
dynamic parseJsonMapToMap(dynamic data) {
  if (data is Map) {
    return Map.fromEntries(
      data.entries.map(
        (e) => MapEntry(
          e.key,
          parseJsonMapToMap(e.value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  if (data is List) {
    return List.from(
      data.map(
        (e) => parseJsonMapToMap(e),
      ),
    );
  }
  return data;
}
```